# Use two Auth-Type in FreeRadius

Tags: openvpn, radius, freeradius, strongswan, freeradius2

I have a RADIUS server with works with mysql, I use this RADIUS for AAA for 2 different services,

Service1 uses Auth-Type as "PAP" and Service2 uses "EAP"

```
radcheck table
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| id  | username | attribute          | op | value        |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| 474 | varun    | Cleartext-Password | := | sunshine3003 |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+


radreply table
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
| id | username | attribute    | op | value |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
|  1 | varun    | Fall-Through | =  | Yes   |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+


radgroupcheck table
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
| id | groupname | attribute | op | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
|  1 | group1    | Auth-Type | := | Local |
|  2 | eapgroup  | Auth-Type | := | EAP   |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+


radusergroup table
+----------+-----------+----------+
| username | groupname | priority |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| varun    | eapgroup  |        1 |
| varun    | group1    |        2 |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to use group "group1" for Service1 and "eapgroup" for Service2
When i check the radius daemon log it shows that it always uses "eapgroup" for both the services.

Maybe because its priority is high ?

I want to it to check auth with "eapgroup" which uses EAP as Auth-Type and if failed it supposed to use "group1" or Auth-Type PAP

Thanks,
Any help will be appreciated.